# More efficient way via VBA to open an external worksheet, export to PDF and close it

Tags: vba, excel, pdf-generation

Wrote this macro that based on a given JobNumber, finds the path where a contract (excel workbook) is, open it, export Sheet1 to PDF, and close it.
Having been testing it and work fine so far.. can anyone point any more efficient way to do what this macro is doing? Perhaps without the need to open the external workbook ?

```
Public Sub saveMePDF()
Dim JobCat As String, JobNumber As String, JobNumberName As String, MainPath As String

JobCat = Sheet1.Range("V2").Text
JobNumber = Sheet1.Range("U2").Text
JobNumberName = Dir("C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumber & "*", vbDirectory)
MainPath = "C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumberName

'set to the current active workbook (the source book)
Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsThis = ActiveSheet

'open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(MainPath & "\Contracts\contract.xlsx")
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'activate the target worksheet
wbTarget.Activate

'export current active worksheet to pathed PDF
If JobNumber <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=MainPath & "\Scheduling\EstimateTest3.pdf" _
, Quality:=xlQualityMedium, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

'close the workbook
wbTarget.Close

'activate the source book again
wbThis.Activate

'clear memory
Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set wbThis = Nothing

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance I have two ideas for you:
1. Switch off screenupdating: 
At the start of the code:

```
Application.screenupdating = false
```

Before end sub at the end:

```
Application.screenupdating = true
```

2. Instead of activating the opened workbook just use it with the assigned name like:

Instead of activeworkbook use your assigned workbook name and then just delete the activate part.

In my experience the above two will increase the speed a lot. 
Please comment how it worked if you try it out.